# How to scroll two vertical splits at the same time?

Tags: cursor-movement, split

I am not sure if it is even possible but, when I am working with vertical splits, sometimes, I want both of them to scroll up/down at the same time rather than using this combination:

1. scroll down <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>
2. focus on left split<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>
3. scroll down <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>
4. focus on right <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

It would be amazing to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and achive to same result.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you review the help? `:he scroll` leads you right through the relevant options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want scrollbind.

Use `:set scb` on each window you which to bind together, then it should be possible to scroll them together.

Additionally this command may come in handy:  `:windo set scrollbind!` - this toggles scrollbind all windows

see `:h scroll-binding`, and `:h scrollbind` for full details.

Also note that `cursorbind`, `diff` and `scrollopt` settings are somewhat related to what you are doing.